# No injectable field found in FXML Controller class

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

It's about JavaFX. When i want to inject fx:id in Scene Builder, i get this warning: 
No injectable field found in FXML Controller class for the id 'something'. 
I wanted to ignore it, and created a function, but it didn't work either. I created mainController class and added it into my FXML file. Here are my codes...

mainController.java

```
package main;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;

public class mainController implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @FXML
    private ProgressBar pb;
    @FXML
    private Slider sl;
        @FXML
        private Label label;

    public void changed(ActionEvent event){

        }
}
```

Main.java

```
package main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/fxml/styles/main.css");

        ProgressBar pb1 = new ProgressBar();
        ProgressBar pb2 = new ProgressBar();

        //pb1.

        //primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Something");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

main.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="main.mainController">
   <children>
      <BorderPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <top>
            <ProgressBar fx:id="pb" prefWidth="200.0" progress="0.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <BorderPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="30.0" left="30.0" right="30.0" top="30.0" />
               </BorderPane.margin>
            </ProgressBar>
         </top>
         <bottom>
            <Slider fx:id="sl" onDragDetected="#changed" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <BorderPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="30.0" left="30.0" right="30.0" top="30.0" />
               </BorderPane.margin>
            </Slider>
         </bottom>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I did same things in my old projects, and they work like a charm. But this one seems not to obey me. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Could you provide the stacktrace? And what about the label? You inject one with the id `label` yet I can't find a label in your FXML. And you could write your `change`-method like: `@FXML private void change() {...}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You're absolutely right, i'm sorry that i've pasted old code here of my FXML in which i hadn't added label, but i've pasted my new controller class code. Another answer solved my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Scene Builder, if the FXML file is associated to a controller class, you know that what makes the connection between the variable in the controller class (`pb`) and the object in the FXML file (`<ProgressBar ... />`) is the value of the object's `fx:id`.

So when you set an `fx:id` on an object, Scene Builder tries to parse the controller class trying to find a variable of that name.

If it doesn't find any, it displays this warning. It's just a reminder that you may want to add such a variable to the controller class, or that you have to choose other valid name from a list.

Since you have `label` defined on your controller, if you try to add a `Label` on Scene Builder, you can get its `fx:id` from the list:

[image: Scene Builder]

But if you assing another name, you will get the warning:

[image: Scene Builder warning]

On a side note, you don't need to instantiate the progress bar on the main class, since it will be instantiated in the controller. And ìf you try to link `change(ActionEvent event)` to a method in Scene Builder (`#change`), you have to annotate it with `@FXML`. Anyway, don't use `onDragDetected` with the slider.

Comment: Adding @FXML before my procedure "changed" worked! Thank you so much! :) Which event do u prefer to use with slider? Thanks in advance...

Comment: You don't really need any from those listed on Scene Builder. You can track changes on the slider by adding a listener to its value property, inside `initialize`: `sl.valueProperty().addListener((obs,ov,nv)->System.out.println(nv));`

Comment: I'll try it as soon as i get home. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

don't forget that Netbeans will Auto-Generate the code in the controller class.

Goto your FXMLDocument.fxml in your Netbeans project, and right click and select: "Make Controller".

Also, remember to save your changes first to your FXMLDocument.fxml, in Scene builder.

Comment: This was helpful. For other IDEs that may not have this feature you can go to Scene Builder and click View > Show Sample Controller Skeleton as well. Then copy that information over to your controller manually.

Comment: @Terry Carter That's such a valuable piece of info I think it should be made into an answer... using IntelliJ and I was just beginning to assume this all had to be typed manually!